# Calling a fragment from Navigational Drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am Having a Navigational Drawer which Consists of n number of menus on clicking the menu I need to open a particular fragment. First I tried it with activities and intent. It doesn't look good, in a case of using fragments. I'm Selecting them by id and calling the fragment from an activity. In the fragment, I'm using pie charts in which it is throwing null pointer exceptions.Ive tried changing from get view since it is only instanciated after Oncreate View. but no results.

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    pieChart1 = (PieChart) getView().findViewById(R.id.piechart1);
    pieChart2 = (PieChart) getView().findViewById(R.id.piechart2);
```

Comment: did you add any view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample code that will help to understand.
First replace the activity_main.xml contents with a fragment in OnCreate():

```
 FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment()).commit();
```

Then replace this HomeFragment with others in onNavigationItemSelected():

```
@Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
        // Handle the camera action
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new HomeFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_current_order) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new MyCurrentOrderFragment(),"Tag").commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_received_images) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new HistoryFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_rate_app) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new RateOurAppFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_help) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new HelpFragment()).commit();
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_settings) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Add a FrameLayout in your content_main.xml and set it's id to "content_frame"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="bd.com.chalo.dsstudio.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:visibility="gone" />
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Ya thanks , Switching to Fragment is working I guess , Its Just Showing null Pointer Exception On this Line   pieChart1 = (PieChart) getView().findViewById(R.id.piechart1);
    pieChart2 = (PieChart) getView().findViewById(R.id.piechart2);`

Comment: fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, new SettingsFragment()).commit(); in this line in content_frame  where we should give the layout i cannot add my layout

Comment: Ive changed everything its still force closing on the same line

Comment: Which error are you getting ? Is it NullObjectReference ?

Comment: Yes java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int) @ tahsinRupam